# Perl CSV to Hash of Arrays natively

Tags: csv, perl, multidimensional-array, scripting

I'm trying to build an associative array from a csv file that stores only unique keys. All without using extra features like Text::CSV
An example text file:

```
emp1,dept1,1090
emp2,dept2,8920
emp3,dept1,3213
emp3,dept2,3234
```

I would like the data to be organized by dept to look like

```
$hash = {
dept=>[dept1, dept2, dept3]
}
```

and within each dept to have its respective emp and ids

So far, I have tried

```
my %hash;
    while (<$fh>){
        my @data = split(/,/, $fh);
        push @{$hash{$_}}, shift @data
            for qw(emp dept id);
    }
```

However, this does not seem to fill the arrays properly and instead just initializes the arrays with no data in them. I've looked all over for examples of how to do this but my searches always contain people mentioning Text::CSV

Comment: What do you want the data structure you're trying to make to look like?

Comment: @Shawn I guess I should have clarified that! I want it to be sorted by dept so deptx: empx, idx

Comment: Hashes are not sorted. If you want sorted data, you have to use an array. Or sort them manually.

Comment: There's a good reason why people suggest using Text::CSV rather than rolling your own naive CSV parser. The module will handle all the edge cases that your code will trip over on, such as "john doe","accounts, admin and wages",1090

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is the with this line

```
my @data = split(/,/, $fh);
```

You are splitting of the filehandle, not the data returned from the `while` statement. That is stored in `$_`

Below is you code changes to fix the `split` line. I'm also using the inline `DATA` filehandle to make it easier on myself. Finally, I've added a call to `Data::Dumper` to see what is getting stored into the hash.

```
use Data::Dumper ;
my %hash;
    while (<DATA>){
        my @data = split(/,/, $_);
        push @{$hash{$_}}, shift @data
            for qw(emp dept id);
    }

print "Hash is " . Dumper(\%hash);
__DATA__
emp1,dept1,1090
emp2,dept2,8920
emp3,dept1,3213
emp3,dept2,3234
```

Running that gives this, which shows the second issue -- you are including a newline in the `id` column

```
Hash is $VAR1 = {
          'dept' => [
                      'dept1',
                      'dept2',
                      'dept1',
                      'dept2'
                    ],
          'emp' => [
                     'emp1',
                     'emp2',
                     'emp3',
                     'emp3'
                   ],
          'id' => [
                    '1090
',
                    '8920
',
                    '3213
',
                    '3234
'
                  ]
        };
```

Fix that with a call to `chomp` before the `split` line

```
use Data::Dumper ;
my %hash;
    while (<DATA>){
        chomp;
        my @data = split(/,/, $_);
        push @{$hash{$_}}, shift @data
            for qw(emp dept id);
    }

print "Hash is " . Dumper(\%hash);
__DATA__
emp1,dept1,1090
emp2,dept2,8920
emp3,dept1,3213
emp3,dept2,3234
```

output is now

```
Hash is $VAR1 = {
          'id' => [
                    '1090',
                    '8920',
                    '3213',
                    '3234'
                  ],
          'emp' => [
                     'emp1',
                     'emp2',
                     'emp3',
                     'emp3'
                   ],
          'dept' => [
                      'dept1',
                      'dept2',
                      'dept1',
                      'dept2'
                    ]
        };
```

That looks better, but you have duplicates in the `hash`. To deal with that, I'm going to store the data read from the CSV as a hash-of-hashes. That will get rid of the duplicates

```
my %hash;
my @cols = qw( emp dept id);

while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp $_;
    my @data = split /,/, $_ ;

    for my $i (0 .. @cols-1)
    {
        # Store as a hash of hashes
        $hash{ $cols[$i] }{ $data[$i] } ++;
    }
}

print "Hash is " . Dumper(\%hash);
```

That looks better - the duplicates are removed

```
Hash is $VAR1 = {
          'dept' => {
                      'dept2' => 2,
                      'dept1' => 2
                    },
          'emp' => {
                     'emp3' => 2,
                     'emp2' => 1,
                     'emp1' => 1
                   },
          'id' => {
                    '3213' => 1,
                    '8920' => 1,
                    '1090' => 1,
                    '3234' => 1
                  }
        };
```

Your requirement was to has a hash of arrays, so add a final step to dump the hash-of-hashes into the format you require

```
my %result;
for my $col (keys %hash)
{
    push @{ $result{$col} }, sort keys %{ $hash{$col} } ; 
} 

print "Hash is " . Dumper(\%result);
```

That outputs this

```
Hash is $VAR1 = {
          'dept' => [
                      'dept1',
                      'dept2'
                    ],
          'emp' => [
                     'emp1',
                     'emp2',
                     'emp3'
                   ],
          'id' => [
                    '1090',
                    '3213',
                    '3234',
                    '8920'
                  ]
        };
```